# Invalid HTTP method: PATCH > executing PATCH : Caused by: feign.RetryableException:

Tags: netflix-feign

we are using netflix feign to make call to restful web service. For patch request it looks like PATCH request is not supported.

> Caused by: feign.RetryableException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
>   executing PATCH
>   https://projects.dev.xyz.com/projects/v1/users/{uid}/projects/{guid}
>         at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:66)      at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:100)
>         at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:74)
>         at
>   feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:54)
>         at
>   com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:294)

Answer (score 21):

if someone encounters the same problem with **spring-cloud-feign**, using the httpClient from feign can be achieved by just adding the maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <!-- Required to use PATCH -->
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${feign.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: True. And if you use the `Feign.builder()` keep on reading the next answer as well... ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/38058469/1326662

Answer (score 14):

You can solve this by using the httpClient from feign. You want to first add the module to your classpath, then configure it when you're building your object with 
`Feign.builder().client(new ApacheHttpClient())`. This adds support for PATCH requests.

Link to Doc: https://github.com/Netflix/feign/tree/master/httpclient

EDIT: there is also a feign object that wraps apache's http client, [link here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.feign/feign-httpclient)

Answer (score 4):

if you using `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign")` and having issue with patch request then you can do below (kotlin) :

Add this dependency

```
 implementation("io.github.openfeign:feign-okhttp:10.2.0")
```

Create below configuration class

```
class FeignOkHttpConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun client(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient()
    }
}
```

and add this configuration to your client (if you like this to be common config for every feign client then you can also add @Configuration for `class FeignOkHttpConfiguration`).

```
@FeignClient(name = "YourClient", url = "\${base-url}", configuration = [FeignOkHttpConfiguration::class])
interface YourClient {

@PatchMapping
fun update(model: YourModel): ResponseEntity<String>

}
```

Comment: adding the okhttp bean and lib was the only method i could get working (Java) spring cloud 2022.0.1 and spring boot 3

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue but managed to solve it by adding the feign-httpclient dependency and adding a additional header X-HTTP-Method-Override : PATCH in the request.

```
<dependency>
    <!-- Required to use PATCH -->
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>${feign.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Add a header

```
@RequestHeader(value="X-HTTP-Method-Override", defaultValue="PATCH") String xHttpMethodOveride
```

Comment: By the Way why we need to add this header?

Answer (score 0):

I have dependency on

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
```

and PATCH caused troubles, also I configured custom client in order to process raw response before mapping to response type.
Solution is to add dependency with proper http client, this for instance

```
implementation group: 'io.github.openfeign', name: 'feign-httpclient', version: '11.7'
```

Then I configured my client with ApacheHttpClient like:

```
    @Bean
    Client customClient(SessionStorage sessionStorage) {
        return new CustomClient(new ApacheHttpClient(), sessionStorage);
    }
```